# flash data to php , automatic store all they email at a folder?

Tags: php, mysql, email

i am new to php and mysql , i just learn how to transferring flash data to php and send to my email.

my intention is , people use my flash project can able to send they email to me.

but problem is , what if 50 people sending they data to my email , and i will be need to open 50 email , and i need to written or type they email to word pad or something.

is they a way or 3rd party system that help me automatic store all they email at a folder ?

can it use to built by php or do i need to drive into mysql server learning ?

can some on point me the into the right direction , i really need to learn this , just let me know where i have to go , i will do the learning my self , thank and appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need a temp store location (Such as **file base**, mysql, others)
2. Revise the sending email (is it PHP??), change **send email** to **write file**
3. Add a new program getting data from **file** (or mysql) for sending email. (You can using the previous send email code)
4. Add a cronjob to visit the program in **step 3** (Also you can use the free website monitor services to replace the cronjob)